# Problem with jquery sortable and click() function

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a list of div elements. 
There is a click function, which does something, when an element is clicked. This works well.
The elements are sortable, too, and this works as well also.

But what also happens (and should not), is that the click function is called after the user sorted the elements.
I need to find a way to not call the click function automatically after elements are sorted. Any ideas?

"return false" in sortable.update does not help

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, just added a varaible mayclick:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  var mayclick = true; 

  $("div.x").sortable({
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        mayclick = false;  
        // some code
        return false; 
    }
  });

  $("div.x").click(function(){
    if (mayclick) {  
      // some code
    } else {
        mayclick = true; 
    }
    return false;
  });
```